# Error in a jpeg image that causes most viewers to crash

Tags: compression, jpeg

I'm trying to learn jpeg and to do this I wrote the hexa of an 8x8 image by hand.
My debugger (Jpeg Snoop) doesn't show any errors. I was also able to decompress it with a C program without any problems.

But the vast majority of image viewers don't want to read it.

Please, can you see an error in my file?

`FF D8 FF DB 00 43 00 03 02 02 02 02 02 03 02 02 02 03 03 03 03 04 06 04 04 04 04 04 08 06 06 05 06 09 08 0A 0A 09 08 09 09 0A 0C 0F 0C 0A 0B 0E 0B 09 09 0D 11 0D 0E 0F 10 10 11 10 0A 0C 12 13 12 10 13 0F 10 10 10 FF DB 00 43 01 03 03 03 04 03 04 08 04 04 08 10 0B 09 0B 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 FF C0 00 11 08 00 08 00 08 03 01 11 00 02 11 01 03 11 01 FF C4 00 14 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 FF C4 00 22 10 00 00 02 0B 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 14 31 00 02 05 11 13 15 21 32 33 53 62 07 17 FF C4 00 15 01 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 06 FF C4 00 28 11 00 00 00 0B 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 11 12 13 14 16 21 31 32 33 61 01 02 04 05 08 17 51 52 63 94 FF DA 00 0C 03 01 00 02 11 03 11 00 3F 00 57 F0 3D 72 76 22 23 30 2E 88 4A 86 B1 C7 98 EB 71 F3 44 D3 B6 F9 61 93 04 DA 3E E5 35 E3 74 34 85 D5 68 1A AD E9 CD 56 20 58 B4 AE 47 79 2A 67 CA 16 3A 5F B3 43 FF D9`

I compared it byte by byte with a valid image but I couldn't find the error

Comment: I already answered your question 2 days ago. Your DHT is invalid.

Comment: what is invalid in my dht ?

Comment: The DHTs are formatted OK in the file but one specifies and generates a lookup table that isn't valid. IJG faults it for creating a dodgy set of bit patterns. However PaintShop Pro v14.3.0.3 will open it. Probably because non of the higher Huffman table entries are ever used it actually doesn't go haywire. The image is black cat in a coal cellar 8x8.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I've found the answer.
one of the codes generated by my huffmann table consists exclusively of 1's. And this is forbidden in jpeg.